# Variable interpolation for a media query property in less - missing closing ")"

Tags: css, less, media-queries

I'm trying to "translate" a sass function into a less function. 
Here is the original SASS one :

```
@mixin bp($feature, $value) {
    // Set global device param
    $media: only screen;

    // Media queries supported
    @if $mq-support == true {

        @media #{$media} and ($feature: $value) {
            @content;
        }

        // Media queries not supported
    } @else {

        @if $feature == 'min-width' {
            @if $value <= $mq-fixed-value {
                @content;
            }
        } @else if $feature == 'max-width' {
            @if $value >= $mq-fixed-value {
                @content;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the function I started to make in less as it seems every declaration can not be implemented the same as in sass :

```
.bp(@feature; @val) when (@mq-support = true) {
    @med: ~"only screen";

    @media @{med} and (@{feature}:@val) {
        @content;
    }
}
```

When I'm compiling this, I got the following error :

```
Missing closing ')' on line 15, column 34:
15     @media @{med} and (@{feature}:@val) {
16         @content;
```

So this error seems to come from the closing @{feature} closing bracket but following the documentation and several blog posts on the internet, it seems that since the 1.6.0 version of less, the css property interpolation is a feature that should work.

Does anybody have an idea of what could be wrong here ? 
Is it actually possible to use a variable as a property in a media query ?

Maybe I'm doing it totally wrong but it seems the [mixins guard feature](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature) in less does not work exactly the same as with SASS and the @if condition so the "translation" is a little bit different.

Thank you in advance

Sébastien

Comment: Why does your sass code contain less variables? @feature but not $feature.

Comment: @3rdthemagical I already replaced the variables and pasted it by mistake... sorry, it should well be $feature EDIT : I updated the original SASS function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpolation or using variables in media queries work slightly differently in Less.

- First of all, you shouldn't use the normal interpolation syntax (`@{med}`). Instead it should just be `@med`.
- Next the second condition should also be set to a variable and then appended to the media query just like the `@med` variable or it should be included as part of the `@med` variable itself. I've given a sample for both approaches below.

```css
.bp(@feature; @val) when (@mq-support = true) {
  @med: ~"only screen and";
  @med2: ~"(@{feature}:@{val})";
  @media @med @med2{
    @content();
  }
}
```

or

```css
.bp(@feature; @val) when (@mq-support = true) {
  @med: ~"only screen and (@{feature}:@{val})";
  @media @med {
    @content();
  }
}
```

---

Below is a sample conversion of that Sass code completely into its Less equivalent. Less does not support the `@content` like in Less, so it should be [passed as a detached ruleset with the mixin call](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature).

```css
@mq-support: true;
@mq-fixed-value: 20px;

.bp(@feature; @val; @content) {
  & when (@mq-support = true) {
    @med: ~"only screen and (@{feature}:@{val})";
    @media @med {
      @content();
    }
  }
  & when not (@mq-support = true) {
    & when (@feature = min-width) {
      & when (@val <= @mq-fixed-value){
        @content();
      }
    }
    & when (@feature = max-width) {
      & when (@val >= @mq-fixed-value){
        @content();
      }
    }
  }
}

a{
  .bp(max-width, 100px, { color: red; } );
}
b{
  .bp(min-width, 10px, { color: blue; } );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your awesome explanation! It's working fine and I understand way better what's happening here. Declaration of a string is a nice workaround. Have a nice day!